# ¿Cómo puedo descartar un AlertDialog que muestra un ReciclerView alimentado por Realm para elegir una opción y el sistema no lo descarta por mi?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, alertdialog, realm

Estoy haciendo una aplicación android que trabaja con una base de datos local que utiliza la librería Realm para crearla y gestionarla. Esta base de datos sirve para guardar artículos que al usuario le gustan dentro de carpetas de favoritos, que el mismo usuario crea, de la misma manera que los usuarios de aplicacines de streaming de música guardan canciones en listas de reproducción.

Para lograr esto hice un AlertDialog que le indica al usuario que seleccione una carpeta (previamente creada por el usuario) para guardar el artículo que se esta mostrando en esa actividad, o que lanza un segundo AlertDialog para crear una nueva carpeta.

```
private Articulo articulo;

private ImageView image;
private TextView titulo;
private TextView contenido;

private String title;
private String article;
private int imagen;

private FloatingActionButton fab;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

private Realm realm;
private RealmResults<Carpeta> carpetas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_articulo);

    //Base de datos, se utilizara en el caso de que el usuario desee guardar este articulo en una carpeta de favoritos
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    carpetas = realm.where(Carpeta.class).findAll();
    carpetas.addChangeListener(this);

    //La actividad anterior me envia mi objeto POJO Articulo, que es el que deseo mostrar en esta actividad
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    articulo = (Articulo) bundle.getSerializable("articulo");

    //Enlazo con mis elementos de la IU
    bindIU();

    //Del objeto POJO Articulo que recibi obtengo los elementos que voy a mostrar en esta actividad y los guardo en variables para utilizarlos
    title = articulo.getTitulo();
    article = articulo.getContenido();
    imagen = articulo.getImagen();

    //Muestro los elementos del POJO en la IU
    Picasso.get().load(articulo.getImagen()).fit().into(image);
    titulo.setText(articulo.getTitulo());
    contenido.setText(articulo.getContenido());

    //Botón flotante que, de ser seleccionado, lanza un AlertDialog para que el usuario guarde este articulo en la base de datos
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fabAgregarCarpeta);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showAlertForRegisterNewArticulo();
        }
    });
}

private void bindIU() {

    image = findViewById(R.id.imageArticulo);
    titulo = findViewById(R.id.textViewArticuloTitulo);
    contenido = findViewById(R.id.textViewArticuloContenido);
}

private void showAlertForRegisterNewArticulo() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_carpeta, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenuCrearCarpetas);
    adapter = new CarpetaAdapter(carpetas, R.layout.alert_dialog_carpeta_item, new CarpetaAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Carpeta carpeta, int position) {
            
            //La variable carpetaId es la PrimaryKey del objeto POJO Carpeta donde se guardara este artículo
            //por lo que debo agregarla al objeto Articulo para que sirva de llave foránea
            int carpetaId = carpetas.get(position).getId();
            //Este método creará un nuevo objeto Articulo y lo guardara en la base de datos, ya con el carpetaId como llave foránea
            createNewArticulo(carpetaId);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Articulo agregado correctamente a la carpeta "+ carpetas.get(position).getTituloCarpeta(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    
    //En caso de que el usuario desee crear una nueva carpeta de favoritos, o de que aún no haya creado ninguna,
    //se lanzará este otro AlertDialog para crear una carpeta cuando se seleccione el botón "Crear carpeta de favoritos"
    builder.setPositiveButton("Crear carpeta de favoritos", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            showAlertForCreatingCarpeta("Crear carpeta de favoritos", "Escribe el nombre para tu nueva carpeta");
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

//AlertDialog para crear una nueva carpeta
private void showAlertForCreatingCarpeta(String title, String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);

    View viewInflated = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_create_carpeta, null);
    builder.setView(viewInflated);

    EditText input = viewInflated.findViewById(R.id.editTextTituloCarpeta);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String carpetaName = input.getText().toString().trim();
            if(carpetaName.length() > 0) {
                createNewCarpeta(carpetaName);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se requiere que insertes un nombre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}

//Método para crear una nueva carpeta
private void createNewCarpeta(String carpetaName) {
    realm.beginTransaction();
    Carpeta carpeta = new Carpeta(R.drawable.secciones, carpetaName);
    realm.copyToRealm(carpeta);
    realm.commitTransaction();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Carpeta " + carpetaName + " creada correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//Método para guardar el artículo visualizado en el presente actividad en la base de datos
private void createNewArticulo(int carpetaId) {

    Articulo seleccion = new Articulo(imagen, title, article, carpetaId);

    realm.beginTransaction();
    realm.copyToRealm(seleccion);
    realm.commitTransaction();
}

//este método actualizara los cambios en el RecyclerView que muestra las carpetas existentes en caso de que el usuario cree una
//carpeta nueva
@Override
public void onChange(RealmResults<Carpeta> carpetas) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Pero mi problema es que cuando el usuario elige una carpeta de las opciones que aparecen en el RecyclerView mostrado en el showAlertForRegisterNewArticulo() y se llama al método createNewArticulo(carpetaId) el AlertDialog se mantiene, y el usuario tiene pulsar el botón de atrás o tiene que seleccionar alguna parte de la pantalla donde no este el AlertDialog para que este desaparezca.

Lo que quiero hacer es que este se descarte cuando se seleccione un elemento del RecyclerView. Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda comunidad.

Comment: simplemente debes escribir `dialog.dismiss();` dentro de `onClick`

Comment: ya lo intente, lo encontre en la documentación de android escribi Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this); y luego dialog.dismiss(); en el método onItemClick pero sigue igual

Comment: debes llamarlo desde el dialog que vas a mostrar, no crear uno nuevo. Te escribí una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cerrar un Dialog se usa el método `dismiss()`. En tu caso sería así

```
private void showAlertForRegisterNewArticulo() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_select_carpeta, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewMenuCrearCarpetas);
    adapter = new CarpetaAdapter(carpetas, R.layout.alert_dialog_carpeta_item, new CarpetaAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Carpeta carpeta, int position) {
            ...
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ...
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Funciono perfectamente. Mi problema era que declaraba el AlertDialog hasta el final del método. Si lo declaro después de asignar el view al builder, como aparece en tu respuesta, puedo invocar al método dismiss(); donde lo necesito. Muchas gracias.